# Tracking parcel API connection

Tags: php, html, api

I have wanted to implement a tracking number API inside my website, the effect should when i type the tracking number, the page will redirect and show the result from the courier company. But i am having trouble to return the result. Can you guys help me to see which part is wrong? Thank you.

```
<?php 
$domain = "https://v2/tracking.html?key=&shipments=";

$action = "EPTrackingBulk";
$postparam = array(
'key'   => '{MY API KEY}',
'shipments'  => array(
array(
'HAWBNo'    => '238725129086',
),
array(
'HAWBNo'    => '238725129086',
),
),
);

$url = $domain.$action;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postparam));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

ob_start(); 
$return = curl_exec($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($return);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($json); echo "</pre>";
?>



    <!-- Tracking -->
                            <form action="<?php echo $url;?>" method="GET">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="shipments" placeholder="Please enter your tracking number" required="" class="form-control box-shadow">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="btn-1">Tracking</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
        </div>
 
    <!-- /.Tracking -->
```

Below here i have also added a script which is the courier given to me:

```
<script>
        {
      "api_status":"Success",
      "error_code":"0",
      "error_remark":"",
      "result":[
        {
          "status_list":{
            "0":{
              "event_date":"2017-10-28",
              "event_time":"11:40 AM",
              "status":"Deliverd",
              "location":"Penang"
            },
            "1":{
              "event_date":"2017-06-28",
              "event_time":"11:40 AM",
              "status":"Parcel has been collected at Penang",
              "location":"Penang"
            },
            "status":"",
            "sender":"Yong Tat",
            "receiver":"Sam"
          },
          "latest_status":"Deliverd",
          "latest_update":"2017-10-28",
          "awb":"238725129086"
        },
        {
          "status_list":{
            "0":{
              "event_date":"2017-10-28",
              "event_time":"11:40 AM",
              "status":"Deliverd",
              "location":"Penang"
            },
            "1":{
              "event_date":"2017-06-28",
              "event_time":"11:40 AM",
              "status":"Parcel has been collected at Penang",
              "location":"Penang"
            },
            "status":"",
            "sender":"Yong Tat",
            "receiver":"Sam"
          },
          "latest_status":"Deliverd",
          "latest_update":"2017-10-28",
          "awb":"238725129086"
        }
      ]
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What does 'having trouble' mean? Are you seeing error messages? Are you getting the wrong data? Something else?

Comment: The api key didnt insert into the link and i have try manually key inside the link it still wont show up the result

Comment: The form has a single `input` element for `shipments` ~ does that take a single value or multiple values somehow? The PHP code shows some static variable declarations within `$postparam` variable - is that just to illustrate sample data?

Comment: The url given above has querystring parameters `key` and `shipments` yet these are empty - are they to be dynamically populated? Also - where is `$action` used?